# In C#, what is the recommended way to parse out a word inside certain characters?

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

In C#, I have a string coming in that I am reading into a variable that looks like this

```
var fullString = "Some random text (importantword)"
```

what is the easiest way to parse out the "importantword"?  RegEx? doing just .IndexOf() for the "(" and ")" characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IndexOf is definitely the easiest.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287734%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Followed by a Substring.

```
var startIndex = fullString.IndexOf("(") + 1;
var endIndex = fullString.IndexOf(")");
var targetWord = fullString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments below, I forgot startIndex was for the opening parenthesis instead of the actual word.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions have two drawbacks: they may be slow compared to `IndexOf()` and they are usually not easy to read and understand. In your case, finding the text in parenthesis is easy and doesn't need regular expressions.

If your string always ends with `)`, then you can search for just the `(` and remove the last character:

```
var start = fullString.IndexOf('(') + 1;
var end = fullString.Length - 1;
return fullString.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Otherwise, do both searches. In this last case, remember to use the `IndexOf(char, int)` overload to avoid searching for the entire string:

```
var start = fullString.IndexOf('(') + 1;
var end = fullString.IndexOf(')', start); // Notice the `start`
return fullString.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Comment: i don't agree with your second drawback. Note that , you can't do all the things with the basic functions.

Comment: i don't know which part of my answer is harder

Comment: @AvinashRaj: this one: `@"(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))"`. You may be comfortable with regular expressions because you're experienced, but I'm pretty sure many average programmers won't be able to read similar expressions with ease or find bugs in them after a glimpse.

Comment: @MainMa I agree 100% on that. This is why I usually avoid Regexes. Code is written once, read many times, so I prefer the intent to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use capturing groups or lookarounds to get all the characters present between `()` brackets.

```
String input = @"Some random text (importantword)";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))");

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

OR

```
String input = @"Some random text (importantword)";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\(([^()]*)\)");

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```